# Rebar3 release ERTS files from host OS?

Tags: linux, windows, erlang, rebar, rebar3

I made a release package with rebar3 command: rebar3 as prod release tar

The executable files contained in myapp/erts-10.0.1/bin are only .exe ones. The files in myapp/bin to start the application are .cmd files.

The operating system where I'm developing on and have installed Erlang OTP21 (64bit) and Rebar3 is Windows7 (64bit).
I wanted to deliver this package to a linux machine (treat it as a embedded target system). But there is nothing in the release package I can execute on linux.
So I asked myself, if rebar3 (if include_erts is true) only packs/uses the Erlang/OTP files for the ERTS folder in the release package, of the current machine it is installed on.
Is that the case?

And if so, I have to install Erlang/OTP and rebar3 on a linux machine and do the release step again to receive a package with executable files for a linux machine?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The files that are the same on different operating systems are the beam files, which are in the lib directory.